# A GRE verbal reasoning question: "served" vs "controlled"

Tags: word-choice

[Source](http://gre.kmf.com/question/32j4tj.html)

> The reclusive clergyman may have lived and died in melancholy, but this doesn’t seem to have (i)_____ his genius in any way. On the contrary, we find ourselves wondering whether his genius wasn’t (ii)_____ in some mysterious way by his mood.
>
> Blank(i)
>
> A. influenced
>   B. hampered
>   C. triggered
>
> Blank(ii)
>   D. served
>   E. controlled
>   F. identified

I think both BD and BE are okay in this question. This clergyman's mood can either serve or control his genius. I can't decide between D or E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for the second blank is definitely "served".

From the phrasing of the second sentence,

> *On the contrary* we find ourselves wondering whether his genius wasn't ______ in some mysterious way by his mood.

we know that we need a word that is the opposite of whatever word we choose for the first blank, which you've correctly indicated should be "hampered". "On the contrary" means that something is the opposite of what you would have expected.

While "controlled" works in the sentence, it doesn't contrast with hampered.

"[Hampered](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hamper)" means

> to make an action intended to achieve something more difficult

So we need a word that means "make something easier". That word, out of the ones given to you, is "[served](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/serve?q=served)" (see fourth definition - verb [help achieve]).

> to help achieve something, or to be useful as something

So, with your *reasoning* question, the logical answer is "served".